# How do I get data from an url using RestKit

Tags: cocoa, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am struggling to understand how I would get image data from an Url using RestKit 2.0. I get an Url from the web-service that looks something like this:

```
"avatar_small_url": "https://www.website.com/grid/avatars/9c10a1c5-1cde-4339-8755-7ff7d17425f6-small.png"
```

What function do I need to use to get the avatar data? 
Any solutions or a small snippet to get me going would really help me out. 
Thanks Al

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall, don't use RestKit for this. RestKit is designed to be used for serialising and deserializing data from JSON / XML / URL form encoded / ... data (not images). Use RestKit for what it is best suited to. RestKit is built on AFNetworking so you have full access to all of those classes - use them when you have a request or response which doesn't require the mapping functionality that RestKit brings to the party.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I realized my thinking-problem. I don't need to get the image to display it, I can just feed it to UImage and take it from there.

```
[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https:.....png"]]
```

That makes my life much easier. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Note that `dataWithContentsOfURL` will download synchronously, so take care calling this from the main thread...

Comment: Better yet, don't call it from the main thread at all. Do the `dataWithContentsOfURL:` message asynchronously on a background queue, and then dispatch back to the main queue with the data.